# Ubuntu MATE vs. Xubuntu for HiDPI screens

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-mate, hdpi

Does Ubuntu MATE offer more features than Xubuntu for users with HiDPI screens and computers with sufficient RAM? If so, what are these features?

Comment: Oops...  Only noticed after answering it was you who posted the question.  Ping me in chat if I misunderstood you...  **;-)**

Comment: Is the below what you were looking for? (I can delete the answer and upvote your question!)

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking for, but I've considered things like HDMI support, DisplayPort support, multiple monitors and display scaling. I'm taking my time waiting to see what the answers are.

Comment: Most of that is graphics hardware related...  I'll delete my answer to leave your question unanswered and upvote the question.

Comment: Another thing to add to my list is that according to an article in Ars Technica *Moving from GNOME/GTK 3.10 to 3.18 ... Mint 18 benefits from much improved high DPI support, which is now just as good as GNOME's* Has MATE also been upgraded?

Comment: [Ubuntu Works with GNOME to Improve HiDPI Support on Linux Desktop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/improved-ubuntu-hidpi-support-in-gnome)

Comment: That's an answer...  :-)

Comment: :D :D :D Upvoted!

Comment: Nothing about Xubuntu?

Comment: Xubuntu is staying minimalistic while Ubuntu MATE is adding full high DPI support.

Comment: As for Xubuntu, there is some support in current releases. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1185237/21005). [Here](https://www.xfce.org/about/tour) you can find information about multiple monitors support in Xubuntu 19.10. I do not know, if you can configure DPI setting for each output separately in any Ubuntu flavor using only GUI tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with mate-desktop-environment 1.20 MATE desktop environment has true HiDPI support. HiDPI is be supported by default in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and later. Every aspect of Ubuntu MATE 18.04, its themes, its applications, its icons and its toolkit assets have been updated to take advantage of HiDPI.

Xfce4 4.14 has true HiDPI support in Ubuntu 19.10 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [my solution using xRandR.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042849/problem-with-scaling-on-debian-based-distro/1042875?noredirect=1#comment1699837_104287)

Tested on (X)ubuntu 18.04 and i believe that i was able to replicate virtual super resolution successfully. Which should be solution for HiDPI as well using something like `--scale 0.5x0.5`.

(☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞