# Problem with scaling on Debian-based distro

Tags: graphics, gui, display-resolution, amd-graphics, scaling

How do you replicate Virtual Super Resolution on Debian based distro?
Or like anything what would make GUI scale to make GUI more productive..

Thanks for any help (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

---

### INFORMATIONS

- This setup has one 1080p 60' monitor that is practically not useble to work with this scale for intended workload (Gaming, Audio-visual production, etc..)
- Temporary GPU - ATI Sapphire 7870 AND AMD Radeon 7870
- AMD has two names for this GPU as far as i know.

  - Comparison in scaling W10 vs (X)ubuntu 18.04 (same device) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mimrn.jpg

---

### TRIED SOLUTIONS

1. Change font size

   - Helped, but not much.
   - I can scale fonts so that its practically unreadable, but GUI stays the same.
2. Change icon size

   - Helped, but not much.
   - Same as fonts, GUI is the same.
3. Switch from XFCE4 on KDE and change DPI for monitor in GUI

   - Helped a lot, but still i need it to scale below “1”.
4. Modify xrandr for virtual resolution

   - it seems to work, but screen can render just 1/4 at a time and the rest is accesable by moving cursor to the edge of the screen. Or it has black screen on ¾ of set screen which are non-useble.
   - Tried command:
     `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1920x1080 --fbmm 2560x1440 --nograb --rate 60`
   - Seems that 3D applications can’t use 2560x1440 and nothing changes. I try to find something usefull in man pages and i found command “--Transform”, but based on provided informations i don’t know how to use it and it seems that it doesn’t have intended effect. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDsh3.jpg
5. Generate resolution using umc ([Universal Moderline Calculator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/?source=typ_redirect)) and add it as mode to xrandr, then run it.

   - Resulted in blackscreen same as cvr.
6. using "--scale" in xrandr allows me to replicate Virtual Super Resolution. (thanks to @Lienhart Woitok)

   - The problem now is that i can't access that part of the screen with cursor, but apps seems to be able to.
   - Testing different presets in xrandr now.

### PROBLEM SOLVED

- PROBLEM SOLVED RUNNING

  `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --fb 2560x1440 --panning 2560x1440 --scale 1.333x1.333 --rate 60`

(Don't copy+paste it into your system, try it with your variables!)

---

### DISCLAIMER

I haven't found any simmilar article on this forum nor on the internet and i can't fix this issue by myself. (☉_☉)

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 18.04 is similar to Xubuntu but with full high DPI support. Try this: [Ubuntu MATE vs. Xubuntu for high DPI screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840552/ubuntu-mate-vs-xubuntu-for-high-dpi-screens)

Comment: @karel Thanks for tip, i try it in VM. (•̀ᴗ•́)و

Comment: `xrandr` has a scale option that might help you. `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --scale 0.5x0.5` or `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --scale 1.5x1.5` depending on which direction you want to scale.

Comment: @LienhartWoitok Man! that's a step to the right direction! Now the problem is that i can't access 3/4 of the screen with mouse, but i can see it. I try to modify xrandr for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by executing:

`xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --fb 2560x1440 --panning 2560x1440 --scale 1.333x1.333 --rate 60`

(Don't copy+paste it into your system, try it with your variables!)

### Special thanks to @Lienhart Woitok. ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ

Answer (score 0):

In KDE Plasma (I'm using Kubuntu 18.04):

1. Settings
2. Display and Monitor
3. Displays
4. Advance Settings
5. Scale Display

Move the slider to the scaling level you desire, click Apply, then reboot.

[image]

Comment: it's "Tried Solution" #3

It helped a lot, but i need it to scale on less then 1 to make it useble for my workload.. :/