# Fractional Scaling 18.04 LTS

Tags: display, scaling

Is fractional scaling ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042849/problem-with-scaling-on-debian-based-distro/1042875#1042875) ) available in 18.04 LTS yet? I am waiting until this is available before I install.

Answer (score 4):

Fractional scaling support in Ubuntu 19.04 and later:

- The Wayland session can now be scaled between 100% and 200% in 25% increments.
- Experimental support in the Xorg session can be enabled to achieve the same. Read more [here](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/x11-hidpi-scaling-available-for-testing-on-disco/10293).

---

> #### Scaling Factor
>
> To enable HiDPI, open *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Displays*， or use gsettings:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
> ```
>
> Note: scaling-factor only allows whole numbers to be set. 1 = 100%, 2 = 200%, etc.
>
> #### Fractional Scaling
>
> A setting of 2, 3, etc., which is all you can do with scaling-factor,
>   may not be ideal for certain HiDPI displays and smaller screens
>   (e.g. small tablets).
>
> **wayland**
>
> Enable fractional scaling experimental-feature:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
> ```
>
> Then open *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Displays*
>
> [image]
>   <sup>**fractional scaling experimental-feature in dconf Editor**</sup>
>
> **xorg**
>
> You can achieve any non-integer scale factor by using a combination of
>   GNOME's scaling-factor and [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution). This combination keeps the TTF
>   fonts properly scaled so that they do not become blurry if using
>   xrandr alone. You specify zoom-in factor with `gsettings` and zoom-out
>   factor with xrandr.
>
> First scale GNOME up to the minimum size which is too big. Usually "2"
>   is already too big, otherwise try "3", etc. Then start scaling down by
>   setting zoom-out factor with xrandr. First get the relevant output
>   name; the example below uses [eDP1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174695/why-is-laptop-screen-called-edp1). Start e.g. with zoom-out 1.25
>   times. If the UI is still too big, increase the scale factor; if it is
>   too small decrease the scale factor.
>
> ```
> xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.25x1.25
> ```

<sub>**Source:** revised from [HiDPI – ArchWiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20200527075050/https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Some applications do not support HDPI scaling. In this case you can call them from the terminal after forcing the scaling factor with `xrandr` first.

For example `kid3` application without forcing scaling factor:

[image: kid3 no scaling]

The default scaling is 96 dpi. So we'll override it by using:

```
xrandr --dpi 144
kid3
```

And now we see:

[image: kid3 with scaling]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method mentioned in the previous answer, I have written a simple GUI application that generates a script and configures it to run every time you login to your account.

You can check the source code and download the AppImage executable at: https://github.com/alex-spataru/hidpi-fixer

I strongly recommend you to click the "Test" button before proceeding to apply the changes.